# How to loop over command result while still running

Tags: bash

I have a script that uses `find` to search for files and loops over the result for further processing.

```
for file in $(find ~ -type f -size +1G); do
     filename=$(basename $file)
     echo $file
done
```

When I run the `find` command directly, it outputs matches directly. But its whin this script, the `loop` first waits for the `find` command to completely finish and afterwards loops over the result.

Is it possible to have the loop run over a match as soon as the `find` command finds any match?

It would be possible with using `pipe` the output, but I want to do more complex stuff in the loop afterwards than simple one line stuff.

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Comment: The `for` loop will not start until its arg list is complete. You could change the construct to `find ... | while IFS='' read -r FN; do` but this can bring its own issues. If (as suggested) you can integrate the processing into `-exec` or `| xargs`, it would be more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use in this way instead:

```
find ~ -type f -size +1G -exec bash -c 'do-stuff-with "$1"' bash_find {} \;
```

Within `find`'s `-exec ... {} \;` construct we open a inline script with `bash -c '...'` that find command will run this for every file it finds.

`bash_find` is the name of our inline script which represent in `$0` for our script and in case of any error stopped the script it will be used to give us a visual output that where the failure come from with printing `bash_find` followed by short description of the error.

Answer (score 0):

See [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) which is relative to the scope of variables and other stuff, depending on what you would use. Also expands on portability across shells. Below examples are for `bash` and GNU null separation.

With process substitution and redirecting to while loop and null separation for the arguments:

```
count=0

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
    printf "%s Processing file: %s\n" "$((++count))" "$f" 
done < <(find -type f -print0)
```

With command grouping:

```
count=0

find -type f -print0 |
    {
        while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
            printf "%s Processing file: %s\n" "$((++count))" "$f" 
        done
    }
```

I have added a variable `count` to demonstrate that for both cases the scope is convenient, you can use into the while loop whatever defined earlier. For the second case, anything introduced into the grouping, will not be accesible afterwards for your script. You can test it by defining a new variable into the grouping and trying to access it later, it will be empty. This is probably a reason to prefer the first way for some cases.